# why returning an **element** from const outcomes as an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, element

the error I get back is: **order is undefined** from the *Console* in the browser

*Whereas* when i substitute *order* with something else like *index* or even an integral ( 5 ), it works just fine. What could possibly be wrong with the order element?

**Thanks in advance!**

```
render() {
const { classes, index, color, order, onClick } = this.props;
return (
  <div
    className={ClassNames({
      [classes.general]: true,
      [classes.borderBlack]: true,
      position:'relative'

    })}
    style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
    onMouseOver={this.mouseOver.bind(this)}
    onMouseLeave={this.mouseOut.bind(this)}
    //----Makes markers clickable
     onClick={onClick}
  >
    {index}
    {this.state.hover ? <div style={{
      color: 'white',
      position:'absolute',
     fontSize:30,
      backgroundColor: 'black'
       }}>{order}</div> : null}
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: have you console log the this.props?

Comment: `What could possibly be wrong with the order element?` It's not defined in props.

Comment: if order present in this.props then it should be destruct. check you this.props by console.log

Answer (score 1):

If `order` isn't in your `props` then you'll get that message. You can either set that as a `defaultProp` on your class, or mark it as `Required` in your `propTypes`.

```
<MyComponent {...otherProps} order={myOrder} /> // has to be there
```